# how to handle out of memory error for Hash set in java

Tags: java, memory-management

I am using HashSet in my program and as the set grows i got the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ".  I'm having 32bit os and 4Gb ram. JVM is not able to allocate more than 1500Mb in VM arguments in eclpse. What to do in this case?

Comment: Show some code, it'll help out.  You shouldn't need 1.5GB for one HashSet.

Comment: Please provide some code. What initial capacity and load factor are you using?

Comment: I'm creating a large hashMap that is having a hashSet as a value and both hashMap and hashSet are growing. I'm having around (45000*45000) integers to be mapped in it

Comment: 45000*45000 = 202500000 times 4 is 8100000000 or 7.5437128543853759765625 Gb, plus object overhead, plus array overhead. It's not going to fit into 4Gb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your heap space memory to increase your heap space, you can use java -Xms -Xmx on the command line. By default, the values are 32m and 128m.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the JVM can only allocate 1500Mb is a 'feature' of the 32-bit JVM. To go beyond this you need to use the 64-bit JVM but you'll also need a 64-bit OS and hardware.

However, it is unlikely you really need this much memory.

There may be good reasons why you are using `Set`s and `Map`s (eg lookups, no-duplicates, etc) but if you don't have these requirements, then you will be able to save memory by using arrays of `int`s, though that obviously has other implications such as how to find the elements you are storing.